# C# good practice to use checkboxes and generate password like this?

Tags: c#

Is it good practice to use my code like this?
My code, basically generates a password with the length of 10(currently), and generates a password according to which checkboxes are checked:
Checkboxes:
- Special characters
- Numbers
- Capital letters

```
    bool c_special = false;
    bool c_numbers = false;
    bool c_capitals = false;

    private void btn_generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        checkCheckboxes();

        if(c_special && c_numbers && c_capitals)
        {
            txt_password.Text = generateWithCharactersAndNumbersAndCapitals(10);
        }
        else if(c_special && c_numbers && !c_capitals)
        {
            txt_password.Text = generateWithCharactersAndNumbers(10);
        }
        else if(c_special && !c_numbers && c_capitals)
        {
            txt_password.Text = generateWithCharactersAndCapitals(10);
        }
        else if(c_special && !c_numbers && !c_capitals)
        {
            txt_password.Text = generateWithCharacters(10);
        }
        else if(!c_special && c_numbers && !c_capitals)
        {
            txt_password.Text = generateWithNumbers(10);
        }
        else if(!c_special && c_numbers && c_capitals)
        {
            txt_password.Text = generateWithNumbersAndCapitals(10);
        }
        else if(!c_special && !c_numbers && c_capitals)
        {
            txt_password.Text = generateWithCapitals(10);
        }
        else if(!c_special && !c_numbers && !c_capitals)
        {
            txt_password.Text = generateNormalPassword(10);
        }

    }

    /*
     * Checks which checkboxes are checked
     */
    private void checkCheckboxes()
    {
        if (cbox_special.IsChecked == true)
        {
            c_special = true;
        }
        else
        {
            c_special = false;
        }
        if (cbox_numbers.IsChecked == true)
        {
            c_numbers = true;
        }
        else
        {
            c_numbers = false;
        }
        if (cbox_capitals.IsChecked == true)
        {
            c_capitals = true;
        }
        else
        {
            c_capitals = false;
        }
    }

    //Normal
    public string generateNormalPassword(int length)
    {
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }

    //Characters
    public string generateWithCharacters(int length)
    {
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }
    public string generateWithCharactersAndNumbers(int length)
    {
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }
    public string generateWithCharactersAndCapitals(int length)
    {
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }
    public string generateWithCharactersAndNumbersAndCapitals(int length)
    {
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }

    //Numbers
    public string generateWithNumbers(int length)
    {
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }
    public string generateWithNumbersAndCapitals(int length)
    {
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }

    //Capitals
    public string generateWithCapitals(int length)
    {
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }

    private void btn_cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to learn better practice than this, I'd love to know your opinion how I have done this and where & how to improve.

Comment: start with pulling sections of these functions that look like they do the same thing out into their own function. then it will be much easier to see what you can do to make the differing parts work with less effort.  the *vast majority* of the code of those many functions are identical.

Comment: If you have a piece of working code and just want to get feedback, you should post this code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: as a side node, you can make your `checkCheckboxes` much simpler and readable: `c_special = cbox_special.IsChecked;` (same for `c_numbers` and `c_capitals`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code now has quite a lot of repetition. Mainly, this part is shared across all the `generate...` methods:

```
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
Random rnd = new Random();
while (0 < length--)
{
    res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
}
return res.ToString();
```

Only the string `valid` is different.

One way to reduce this repetition is to have one `generate` method that takes flag arguments:

```
// rnd should be at class level so you don’t create a new one every time
Random rnd = new Random();
public string generateWith(int length, bool capitals, bool numbers, bool symbols) {
    string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if (capitals) { // add the capitals to 'valid' }
    if (numbers) { // add the numbers to 'valid' }
    if (symbols) { // add the symbols to 'valid' }
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

    while (0 < length--)
    {
        res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
    }
    return res.ToString();
}
```

And then you just have to pass the variables `c_special`, `c_numbers` and `c_capitals` into this method:

```
generateWith(10, capitals: c_capitals, numbers: c_numbers, symbols: c_special);
```

Comment: And pull the new Random(); to do it only once.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank u for helping me out! It makes more sense now :D

Comment: @ToastyTeddy if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark!